# Can a triangle and its Euler line be described as the projection of an equilateral triangle and line orthogonal to it in 3D space?

Tags: geometry, triangles

The guys over at Numberphile have a great video on the Euler line of a triangle. At the time referenced at the following link, they use a computer simulation to show the movements of the orthocenter, medicenter, and circumcenter of a triangle as it changes shape. As I watched the video, the movements of the triangle and its Euler line started to look three dimensional.

https://youtu.be/wVH4MS6v23U?t=417

I have seen a proof of of the statement "every triangle is the orthogonal projection of some equilateral triangle." However, I cannot find a reference to Euler lines of the projection and whether there is a corresponding line through the equilateral triangle that correlates to the Euler line of the projection.

So the full question is thus: Can a triangle and its Euler line be described as a projection into two dimensions of an equilateral triangle and an orthogonal line through its medicenter sitting in three dimensions? Or is my intuition just completely off?

Comment: The projection of the perpendicular bisector will still go through one of the vertices of the triangle.

Comment: @MarkBennet I was unclear in the title for brevity. What I meant by perpendicular bisector is more fully explained in the last paragraph of the question: Can a triangle and its Euler line be described as a projection into two dimensions of an equilateral triangle and an orthogonal line through its medicenter sitting in three dimensions?

Comment: This is an interesting question! Unfortunately, I believe the answer is no. Consider an isosceles triangle with two long edges and one short edge, e.g. at time 7:11 in the video. The Euler line coincides with the longest median, but the projection of the 3D line you are thinking of would be perpendicular to it.

Comment: @Rahul Yes! That definitely counters it for me. Thank you!